# Where is the theory about "binary toggling games"?

Tags: complexity-theory, combinatorics, binary, computer-games, xor

Let us -- using parameters $M, N$ and $L$ --

1. create an ordered set of size $M$ of $N$-bit long vectors $V$ and initialize them randomly: $V_k[i] = b \sim Bin(n=1, p=0.5)\ \forall i \in 
   \{0\ ..\ N-1\}, \forall k \in \{0\ ..\ M-1\}$.
2. create an N-bit long vector $A_0$ and initialize it to ones.
3. create an $M$-bit long vector $S$ and initialize it randomly in the same manner as any $V_k$.
4. for $i$ from $0$ to $M$, if $S[i] = 1$, then $A_i = A_{i-1} \oplus V_i$, otherwise $A_i = A_{i-1}$, resulting in $A_M$ after $M$ steps
5. present an agent/player with $A_M$ together with all vectors $V_k$ and make him return $S$ or the set of indices of vector $S$ where $S[i] = 1$. It follows that $A_M \oplus V_{i_0} \oplus V_{i_1} \oplus V_{i_2} \oplus\ ...\ \oplus V_{i_{last}} = A_0$.

A simple example with $N=4$ and $M=3$:

$A_M = [0, 1, 0, 1]$, $V_0 = [1, 1, 0, 1]$, $V_1 = [0, 0, 1, 1]$, $V_2 = [0, 1, 1, 1]$

solution $\rightarrow S = [1, 0, 1],$ because $A_M \oplus V_0 \oplus V_2 = [1, 1, 1, 1]$

This problem occurs in many games I have encountered and never really gave it much thought, until now. For the purpose of this question, I have called it the "binary toggling game".

What I wonder is:

- what are "binary toggling games" really called
- what is the theory being them: algorithms, their complexity (classes), edge cases, etc.

Could you please provide links? I hope they exist.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're describing here. Are you simply asking about the problem of finding indices s.t. the equation in point 5 holds? The [lights out puzzle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html) seems to be a special case of this problem.

Comment: @Discretelizard yes, the lights out is definitely a special case of this problem, thanks for finding out. I have expected this problem to have a general name, since I've encountered  many of its variants, like the lights out puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Binary toggling games" are generally just arithmetic problems over [GF(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field).

Your particular problem is equivalent to the following over GF(2):

$$\sum_i V_iS_i = 1 + A_M $$

If we write $\vec{S} = [S_1, S_2, \dots]^T$ and $V = [V_1, V_2, \dots]^T$ we find that your problem is actually a simple matrix equation over GF(2):
$$V\vec{S} = 1 + A_M$$

You can solve this problem using Gaussian elimination over GF(2). In your example:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c@}  
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\  
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right) \longrightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c@}  
 \color{red}1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\  
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)\longrightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c@}  
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\  
 0 &\color{red}1 & 1 & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\longrightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c@}  
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\  
 0 &1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & \color{red}1 & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

From which we can read off that $S_1 = 1$, $S_2 = 0$ and $S_3 = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.